# Get SQL Error 20006 during Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, freetds, seeding

I'm trying to migrate some data by using laravel seeders. My seeder takes some records from a MSSQL database and insert it into a MySQL.

The point is that it takes the data correctly from MSSQL but, when starting to insert in MySQL, it throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20006 Write to the server failed [20006] (severity 9) [(null)]
```

I'm working over a VPN since both DDBB are in Azure cloud. I'm launching the seeder from a local container in Docker, whose .env is pointing to both databases.

The same seeder works fine when I change the MySQL connection into a local database, what makes me think there's some kind of connection error with the actual MySQL database, but I can't really find it. Everything seems to be right.

I'm about killing myself. Any idea, please?

Comment: The MySQL Server dropped the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It was a problem with the memory.

In my script, I used `chunk` to do the operations by blocks. I had set blocks of 200 operations, so it couldn't work with such amount of records at the same time.

I changed the number into 50 and everything is working now.